# How to give a formula values in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, formula

I have a program that is supposed to create a pdf file of actograms given a csv of activity and time. I need to loop through multiple activity columns, one for each subject. The first activity column is column 3. Here is the relevant code:

```
pdf("All Actograms.pdf")
for(i in 3:(length(dat) - 1)) {
  activity <- colnames(dat)[i]

  # Plot the actogram
  print(actogram(activity~datetime, dat=dat, col="black", main=colnames(dat)[i], strip.left.format="%m/%d", doublePlot = TRUE, scale=0.75))
}
dev.off()
```

When I call my actogram function, I get the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator." The problem is the formula "activity~datetime," because datetime is a column name and activity should be too. If I try it out of the loop, with the name of an activity column rather than a variable containing the name, it works fine. Upon debugging, I found the actogram function is receiving the string "activity," rather than the variable activity. I don't really understand formulas, but I want to know if there's any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, which is loop through many columns, changing the column before the "~" each time I call the actogram function. I'm very new to R.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple way is to add `dat$Yvar <- dat[,activity]`, and then `Yvar ~ datetime` as your formula.

Comment: replace `activity~datetime` with `reformulate(datetime, activity)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have the data you are working on but I think the simplest thing you can do is the following:

```
pdf("All Actograms.pdf")
for(i in 3:(length(dat) - 1)) {

  activity <- colnames(dat)[i]#save the name of the column I  
  colnames(dat)[i] <- "activity" # change the name of column I to activity
   # Plot the actogram
  print(actogram(activity~datetime, dat=dat, col="black", main=activity, strip.left.format="%m/%d", doublePlot = TRUE, scale=0.75))

   colnames(dat)[i] <- activity # change back the name of the column I to its original name
 }
dev.off()
```

Hopefully it works.